# Deleting specific columns in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel table in the following format:

[image: excel file]

I just want to delete those columns that do not have the value of 1 in the first row("A"). I know that for deleting a column I can use something like:

```
Columns("E:E").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Any help it would be great.

Some solution that gives me error is:

```
Sub Delete_Column_Excel_VBA()
    Dim Firstcolumn, fcol As Long
    Dim Lastcolumn As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        .Select
        Firstcolumn = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Column
        Lastcolumn = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
        For fcol = Firstcolumn To Lastcolumn
            With .Cells(fcol, "1")
                If .value <> 1 Then .EntireColumn.Delete
            End With
        Next fcol
    End With
```

If I delete those columns that do not have the value of 1 in the first row my table should look at the end like this:

[image: excel table 2]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all ? You should at least be able to come up with some pseudo-algorithm.

Comment: What error do you get ? On what line ?

Comment: application define or object define error in the line With .Cells(fcol, "1")

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Delete_Column_Excel_VBA()
    Dim cl As Range, rng As Range

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
        If cl <> 1 Then
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Set rng = cl
            Else
                Set rng = Union(rng, cl)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    rng.EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks I have updated how I would like the final table to look, could you check it up?

Comment: Thank you @chris neilsen, I have modified it and now I got the result that I want

Answer (score 0):

This fixes your bug but I think there is still a logical error left after that:

```
With .Cells(fcol, 1)
```

Excel expects the reference to be expressed as numbers, not as strings of characters like you did. Then in your `if` I think it should be the opposite. You should probably compare against "1" because otherwise it just deletes everything (tried on my computer).

Comment: Thanks, stills delete everything, I just need to delete those columns that have a 1 in row 1, and to move the remaining values to the left